# How to create a class inside a class

Tags: javascript

I've been programming in Java for a while.
The following can be done in Java:

```
public class Parent
{
    public static class Child
    {
    }
}
```

Then a new instance of it can be called like `new Parent.Child();`

I was wondering if the same can be achieved in JavaScript. Could someone tell me how to do this, and explain how and why it works? (I'm still not really used to the way OO-JavaScript handles classes, etc.)

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: Javascript is prototype based, and does'nt really have classes in that sense, more like psuedo classes really.

Comment: JavaScript only has (constructor) functions. You can assign a function as property of another function if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Just as a complete general comment on the topic. Under JavaScript Harmony I found this: [**harmony:classes**](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:classes) which links into the following proposal: [**strawman:maximally_minimal_classes**](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes) I also came across this short article on [**Classes in JavaScript ES6**](http://h3manth.com/content/classes-javascript-es6) All very interesting and exciting in regards to classes in JavaScript.